# How to make a Splash Screen wait a few seconds before start fading out?

Tags: c#, .net, splash-screen

I have a windows form which i created for my splash screen, i added a timer to this form, enabled it and added the lines below in my code :

```
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Opacity -= 0.01;

        if (this.Opacity <= 0)
        {
            this.Close();
        }   
    }
```

The splash screen fade out, but the problem is that i want it to be 100% visible ( opacity = 1.0 ) for 5 secondes then it start fading out till it closes!

I tried to add this line in the beginning of my code :

```
     Using System.Threading;
```

I disabled the timer1, Then i added the line below on the form load event

```
      Thread.Sleep(5000);
      timer1.Enabled = true;
```

But un fortunately that doesn't work for me, this makes the application wait for 5 secondes before even showing the splash screen, then it shows it and fade it instantly.

How can i make the splash screen appear for 5 seconds then it fade out ?

Anyhelp would appreciated

Comment: Most annoying splashscreen ever

Comment: I'm with James on this one.  Consider the users of your application - splash screens are supposed to give you something to look at when your application is initializing.  If you have nothing to initialize you're just making your users wait after the initial appeal of the cool splash screen has gotten old.

Answer (score 1):

Initially set your timer's interval to 5000.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    timer1.Enabled = false;
    timer1.Tick -= timer1_Tick;
    timer1.Tick += FadeOut;
    timer1.Interval = /* whatever your original interval was */
    timer1.Enabled = true;
} 

private void FadeOut(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    this.Opacity -= 0.01; 

    if (this.Opacity <= 0) 
    { 
        this.Close(); 
    }    
}
```

This will cause the timer to first delay 5 seconds, then reuse the timer to perform the opacity change.

If the Thread.Sleep() call was blocking your application, that indicates you are not running the splash screen on a separate UI thread.  Typically you want your splash screen to be displayed in parallel as your application initializes.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add *another* variable controlling the opacity in that five second period, something like `myOpacity` initialised to (assuming your timer is a hundredth of a second) `6`:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.myOpacity -= 0.01;
    if (this.myOpacity <= 0)
        this.Close();
    else
        if (this.myOpacity <= 1)
            this.Opacity -= this.myOpacity;
}
```

That way in the first five seconds (where `myOpacity` runs from 6 down to 1), nothing will change. Then, in that final second it will fade out.